# Rails eroor while installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi can u help me with this problem :

```
spree install
[WARNING] Spree CMD Installer is deprecated. Please follow installation instructions at https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] 
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] 
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_gateway
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
Could not find gem 'spree_auth_devise (~> 3.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

when i am typing bundle install it says :

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.1.0) ruby depends on
      spree_frontend (= 3.1.0) ruby depends on
        jquery-rails (~> 4.1) ruby

    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
```

please help me i was creating ecommerce website

Comment: This is mostly dependencies issue. try installing jquery-rails gem. gem install jquery-rails

Answer (score 1):

You're using Rails 4.1, but Spree 3.1 requires Rails 4.2.6 as detailed in the [README](https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started).

Update the `rails` line in your Gemfile to `gem "rails", "4.2.6"`, and good luck with your website.